# How to suggest an edit

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

I have just learned that users with 2000+ reputation points on SO can suggest to edit answers.

I always edited questions and never edited answers.

So the question is: if I click to edit an answer, will the edit appear immediately or will it just be a suggested edit needing approval (I would test it but I don't want to edit an answer even if it's not needed)?

Comment: The same rules and reputation for editing questions. If you have 2k+, edits will happen immediately.  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only users with less than 2,000 reputation can suggest edits to anything.

Users with 2,000 reputation but less than 20,000 reputation can only suggest edits to tag wikis and their excerpts; any changes they make to questions or answers are immediate (don't require approval).

Users with 20,000 or more reputation can no longer suggest edits of any kind; all of their edits are immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Anyone can suggest edits to questions and answers, even anonymous users. It takes 2000 rep to edit without peer review.

So you can edit an answer if you have 2000 or more reputation, else you can suggest an edit.